# Pass a variable in sendKeys e2e testing using protractor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I am new to e2e testing and I am writing e2e test cases for my angular aplication. Here I am creating a patient and I want to book an appointment for the same patient. 
This is the code

```
 it('Add Patient', function(){   

    var fname = element(by.model('newrecord.firstName')).sendKeys('Riaz');
    element( by.css('[ng-click="ok()"]') ).click();
});

it('Create Appointment', function(){ 

     element(by.model('newrecord.patientId')).sendKeys(fname);
});
```

I am getting the below error

```
ReferenceError: fname is not defined
```

How to pass variable to sendKeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Page Object
var recordPage = {
 firstNameElm: element(by.model('newrecord.firstName')),
 patientIdElm: element(by.model('newrecord.patientId')),
 okBtnElm:     element(by.css('[ng-click="ok()"]')),
};

// Test data
var testData = {
  patient: {
    idTxt: 'Riaz001',
    firstName: 'Riaz',
  },
};

it('adds patient', function() {
  recordPage.firstNameElm.sendKeys(testData.patient.firstName);
  recordPage.okBtnElm.click();
});

it('creates an appointment', function() {
  // not sure what you want to send here but should be text not an ElementFinder
  recordPage.patientIdElm.sendKeys(testData.patient.idTxt);
});
```